# how can i change lavamap (jquery menu) size (width)?

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2010, plugins, lavalamp

i am using lavalamp jquery menu as my menu...

every thing is ok (like it's sample) in my project...

but i could n't change it's size horizontally...

how can i do that ?

my asp.net code (with html) :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Amlak.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/LavaLamp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document.body).ready(function () {

            $("#1").lavaLamp({
                fx: "backout",
                speed: 700,
                click: function (event, menuItem) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

                });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MenuDiv" dir="rtl">
        <h3>
            With Image</h3>
        <ul class="lavaLampWithImage" id="1">
            <li><a href="#">home 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">home 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">home 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">home 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and css code is like this :

```
.lavaLampWithImage
{
    position: relative;
    height: 29px;
    width: 421px;
    background: url("../Images/bg.gif") no-repeat top;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.lavaLampWithImage li
{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}
.lavaLampWithImage li.back
{
    background: url("../Images/lava.gif") no-repeat right -30px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
}
.lavaLampWithImage li.back .left
{
    background: url("../Images/lava.gif") no-repeat top left;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 9px; /* 7px is the width of the rounded shape */
}
.lavaLampWithImage li a
{
    font: bold 14px tahoma;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    top: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto 10px;
}
.lavaLampWithImage li a:hover, .lavaLampWithImage li a:active, .lavaLampWithImage li a:visited
{
    border: none;
}
```

for upper codes every thing is ok.

but when i change menu (increase li menu) like this :

```
    <ul class="lavaLampWithImage" id="1">
        <li><a href="#">home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

so every thing is commixed...

for solving this issue i changed width: 421px; to width: more; => not help

for another purpose i want to have a little menu (my main goal)

so my menu should be like this :

```
<ul class="lavaLampWithImage" id="1">
    <li><a href="#">home 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

for this job i never could change the width to lower.

mean changing width:421px; to width:lower; not help.

should i change something inside jquery libraries ?

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thought we can change the width with css rules / but i figured out for changing the width we should change the background of menu in photoshop ...